# Paypal Location Issue with @paypal/react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, shipping-method

I have a problem with paypal integration to my react project.
Actually I have implemented the paypal with this code.

```
const onCreateOrder = (data, actions) => {
  return actions.order.create({
    intent: "CAPTURE",
    application_context: {
      shipping_preferences: "NO_SHIPPING",
    },
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {
          value: 150,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
};
```

But with this code, users can't input address on paypal platform. So I updated the code like this.

```
const onCreateOrder = (data, actions) => {
  return actions.order.create({
    intent: "CAPTURE",
    application_context: {
      shipping_preferences: "GET_FROM_FILE",
    },
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {
          value: 150,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
};
```

Then I get this error on paypal.
[This is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2LUR.png)

Could you please help me here?
Thank you.

I tried to change the address several times but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the screenshot occurs when there is an `onShippingChange` callback function that rejects the promise (does not return successfully).

The callback function [is documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/#onshippingchange). If you do not need it, remove its definition from your buttons component. If you do need it, debug and correct it to work as it should.

Comment: Hi, Preston, your answer is working like magic.
Actually, I have code on onShippingChange (just simple console)
after I removed that event handler, everything is solved.

Comment: I'd love to vote your answer for a hundred times, but I couldn't. lack of reputation.